# Two footers not printed in pdf and excel format when clicked in button in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Actaullay I have buttons to save in pdf and excel format.I have two footers coming from json as Total and Percentage.When i click the Button then only Total footer is coming but the Percentage row is not coming in the pdf and excel files.I need to show both the footer but it is not coming.

```
<table id="report46Table" class="display responsive nowrap" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Disturbance</th>
                            <th>Zero</th>
                            <th>Minor</th>
                            <th>Medium</th>
                            <th>Major</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Occurance</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr id="fTotal">
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                        <tr id="fPercentage">
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>

                    </tfoot>

                </table>
```

script to load the datatable is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var report46Data = [];
        var report46Footer = null;
        var report46Table = $('#report46Table').DataTable({
            data : report46Data,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                {
          extend: 'excel',
          footer: true,
        text : 'Export to Excel',

          messageTop: 'Records of forest disturbances in the forest',
              filename: function(){

                  return 'report46';
              },
                },

                {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        footer: true,
        //orientation : 'landscape',
        pageSize: 'TABLOID',
        text : 'Export to Pdf',
        messageTop: 'Records of forest disturbances in the forest',
        title: '',
        filename: function(){

                return 'report46';
            },
                },

            ],
            ordering: false,
            "paging" :false,
            columns : [ {
                "data" : "disturbanceName"
            }, {
                "data" : "iZero"
            }, {
                "data" : "iMinor"
            }, {
                "data" : "iMedium"
            } ,{
                "data" : "iMajor"
            },{
                "data" : "total"
            },{
                "data" : "occurance"
            }],
            "footerCallback" : function(row, data, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api();
                if (report46Footer) {
                    $($("#fTotal")[0].cells[0]).html(report46Footer[0].disturbance);
                    $($("#fTotal")[0].cells[1]).html(report46Footer[0].iZero);
                    $($("#fTotal")[0].cells[2]).html(report46Footer[0].iMinor);
                    $($("#fTotal")[0].cells[3]).html(report46Footer[0].iMedium);
                    $($("#fTotal")[0].cells[4]).html(report46Footer[0].iMajor);
                    $($("#fTotal")[0].cells[5]).html(report46Footer[0].total);
                    $($("#fTotal")[0].cells[6]).html("");

                    $($("#fPercentage")[0].cells[0]).html(report46Footer[1].disturbance);
                    $($("#fPercentage")[0].cells[1]).html(report46Footer[1].iZero);
                    $($("#fPercentage")[0].cells[2]).html(report46Footer[1].iMinor);
                    $($("#fPercentage")[0].cells[3]).html(report46Footer[1].iMedium);
                    $($("#fPercentage")[0].cells[4]).html(report46Footer[1].iMajor);
                    $($("#fPercentage")[0].cells[5]).html(report46Footer[1].total);
                    $($("#fPercentage")[0].cells[6]).html("");
                }
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url : A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/api/report46/all",
            method : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(response) {
                report46Data = response.dataList;
                report46Footer = response.footer;

                report46Table.rows.add(report46Data).draw();
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: can you create fiddle for you code?

Comment: it is working right except that footer section problem.you can just see the small code above.

Comment: No, this small code doesn't explain issue. If you can create fiddle, i can help you to fix.

Comment: ok i will make fiddle and ask you.Thanks for cooperation